# Make Twitter Bootstrap Table's right most column flush against the edge

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Twitter-Bootstrap (3.0) to design a project website for school, we're making an online Risk clone, with independant turns like Words With Friends.  I use an HTML table to displays the player's list of current games and I would like to make it so the right-most column is flush against the edge and doesn't have a lot of extra white space.

Here is my dummy table:

```html
<table class = "table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Game ID </th>
            <th> Status </th>
            <th> Players </th>
            <th> Turn </th>
            <th> Last Turn </th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td> 1 </td>
           <td> IN PROGRESS </td>
           <td> 4/4 </td>
           <td> tedbeem </td>
           <td> 11/12/13 6:30 PM </td>
           <td> <button class = "btn btn-primary"> View </button> </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td> 2 </td>
           <td> RECRUITING </td>
           <td> 4/5 </td>
           <td> N/A </td>
           <td> 11/12/13 3:10 PM </td>
           <td> <button class = "btn btn-primary"> View </button> </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td> 13 </td>
           <td> IN PROGRESS </td>
           <td> 3/3 </td>
           <td> D-Halt-on </td>
           <td> 11/12/13 9:00 AM </td>
           <td> <button class = "btn btn-primary"> View </button> </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

An example of what I want it to look like can be found here: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/table-with-users

What they did is give the last element a fixed width and somehow it works.  Can someone explain this or give my a better solution?

Comment: It looks like text-align could get the job done but I'm not sure that's the solution I want to go with.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that the last column *(which is **right** aligned)* takes up more space than the button inside it *(which is **left** aligned)* needs.

[image: column]

### To fix this, you can do either of the following:

1. Shrink the column to take up a smaller amount of space, so the button appears to hug the right*:

   ```css
   table tr td:last-child {
       white-space: nowrap;
       width: 1px;
   }
   ```
2. Right align the content of the last row so the button aligns to the right size of all the space it is allotted.

   ```css
   table tr td:last-child {
       text-align: right;
   }
   ```

***Note**: The sample went with the first option by applying an inline style to the last header, effectively setting the width for the whole column with `<th style="width: 36px;"></th>`

## [Working Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/dqq5B/)

Which will look like this:

[image: demo]

Answer (score 9):

Using the Bootstrap framework, you can simply add the **text-right** class to the last td cell.
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-emphasis (Scroll down to the Alignment classes)

If you want to make your buttons smaller, look into the button sizing classes: **btn-sm** or **btn-xs**
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#buttons-sizes

Comment: nice and clean without extra styles :)

Answer (score 5):

It's just how tables work, what I would do is this:

Give your table an ID

```html
<table id="my_table">
```

Specify this:

```css
#my_table tbody tr td:last-child {
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 1%
}
```

Basically compress the last column as much as you can but do not wrap anything.